# Establecer formato a Textbox en C# para proyecto WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, formato, textbox

Estoy creado un proyecto en WPF en el cual en algunos textbox tengo que ingresar horas en el formato 00:00:00, quisiera que el texbox ya tenga el formato predefinido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entre los controles del `wpftoolkit` cuentas con el

[TimePicker](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/TimePicker)

con este podrias seleccionar un horario con el formato que necesitas ya que tiene una propiedad para cambiarlo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si necesitas que se pueda escribir la hora lo mas cercano seria usar el `MaskedTextBox` aplicando el formato de hora

[WPF MaskedTextBox Control](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/wpf-maskedtextbox-control/)

el wpftoolkit tambien tiene un control algo mas avanzado para esto

[MaskedTextBox](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/MaskedTextBox)

Comment: Necesito ingresar todo tipo de horas. "03:23:35" y así, por eso ocupo un texbox, y esperaba que hubiera una forma de que ya esté establecido el formato en el texbox

Comment: en el textbox no, para eso existe el MaskedTextBox que es como el textbox pero puedes definirle una mascara

Comment: @Magdaleno si esta respuesta solucionó tu problema, por favor [acepta la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Saludos.

Comment: Disculpa, yo trabajo en eso proyecto en la tarde, aún no pruebo la respuesta.

Comment: El control TimePicker también permite escribir la hora, y obviamente la valida, no se requiere de un maskedtextbox.